# Checking if data already is present in database

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I'm trying to check if an user id already exists in the database. But for some reason it doesn't work. I've tried different sollutions but all failed.

db_connect.php is working fine, i double checked!

create_user.php

```
<?php

$response = array();

if (isset($_POST['user_id'])){

        $id = $_POST['user_id'];
        $fullName = $_POST['user_fullName'];
        $firstName = $_POST['user_firstName'];
        $lastName = $_POST['user_lastName'];
        $birthday = $_POST['user_birthday'];
        $friends = $_POST['user_friends'];
        $totalFriends = $_POST['user_totalFriends'];
        $email = $_POST['user_email'];
        $gender = $_POST['user_gender'];
        $likes = $_POST['user_likes'];
        $events = $_POST['user_events'];
        $hometown = $_POST['user_hometown'];

    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'userData' WHERE 'id' = '$id'");
    $user_data = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if(empty($user_data)) {         

        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO userData(id, fullName, firstName, lastName, birthday, friends, totalFriends, email, gender, likes, events, hometown) VALUES ('$id', '$fullName', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$birthday', '$friends', '$totalFriends', '$email', '$gender', '$likes', '$events', '$hometown')");

        if($result){
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "User successfully created";

            echo json_encode($response);
        }

        else{
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Error occurred";

            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }

    else {

        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "User already in database";

        echo json_encode($response);            

    }
}

else{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required userdata is missing";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

?>

Well. If i run this script in a browser it works perfectly. When i run it in my android app it always creates a new user.

Thanks! T

Comment: `SELECT * FROM 'userData' WHERE 'id'` get rid off single quotes on table and column names.

Comment: What isn't working? Is there an error you can show, or behaviour you can describe?

Comment: Please read up on SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added single quotes around table name and field.

Change it to back ticks.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'userData' WHERE 'id' = '$id'");
```

Update to:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `userData` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
```

**Also, please don't use mysql_* functions as they are deprecated for security reasons and will be removed in future versions.**

Single quotes are for user input.

Keywords/Database name/Table Name/Field Names can be enclosed with back ticks.

Comment: Thanks, There was indeed a problem with my ticks. But is still doesn't solve my problem. I edited my question.